# Trouble with boolean

Tags: python, printing, boolean

I created a very simple code and I am having trouble in display the boolean value for it. I will place the full code (including extra printing, but my trouble is on displaying True or false here: print("Output X is:", **AND(a, b)**)

The code:

```
#-------------------------|
def AND(a,b):
  
  if a == 1 and b == 1:
    return True
  else:
    return False
#-------------------------|
# main function
    
if __name__=='__main__':
#-------------------------|  Truth Table
  print("--> False | OFF | 0" )
  print("--> True  | ON  | 1" )
  print( )
  print("-------------------------------------")
  print("|     Truth Table for AND gate      |")  
  print("-------------------------------------")
  print("| A = False | B = False | X =",AND(False,False),"| ")
  print("| A = False | B = True  | X =",AND(False,True),"| ")
  print("| A = True  | B = False | X =",AND(True,False),"| ")
  print("| A = True  | B = True  | X =",AND(True,True)," | ")
  print("-------------------------------------")
  print( )
  print("* AND gate output is TRUE only if both inputs are TRUE" )
#-------------------------|
  print( )
  print( )
a= input("Enter a value for input A (0,1): ");
b= input("Enter a value for input B (0,1): ");
print("Output X is:", AND(a, b))
```

Comment: You forgot to describe your "trouble".

Comment: You are comparing integers to strings. While `True == 1`, `"1" != 1`.

Comment: add int() infront of your input() like so: `a= int(input("Enter a value for input A (0,1): "))`

Comment: And please don't use semicolens. It's unpythonic.

Comment: yep. Thank you, Eugene! It is working now

Comment: Thanks, Robin! semicolons removed.

Comment: Thanks, testfile! It is working as expected.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

When you use "input" it saves it as a string. So you have to convert it to an integer with `int(input("Enter a value for input A (0,1): "))`.

Also,there's no need for the `if` in your function `AND`. See the shorter function `AND_V2`

```
def AND(a,b):

    if a == 1 and b == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def AND_V2(a,b):
    # short version of function "AND"
    return a == 1 and b == 1

# main function

print( )
print( )

print("--> False | OFF | 0" )
print("--> True  | ON  | 1" )
print( )
print("-------------------------------------")
print("|     Truth Table for AND gate      |")
print("-------------------------------------")
print("| A = False | B = False | X =",AND(False,False),"| ")
print("| A = False | B = True  | X =",AND(False,True),"| ")
print("| A = True  | B = False | X =",AND(True,False),"| ")
print("| A = True  | B = True  | X =",AND(True,True)," | ")
print("-------------------------------------")
print( )
print("* AND gate output is TRUE only if both inputs are TRUE" )
#-------------------------|
print( )
print( )
a= int(input("Enter a value for input A (0,1): "));
b= int(input("Enter a value for input B (0,1): "));

print("Output X is with V1:", AND(a, b))
print("Output X is with V2:", AND_V2(a, b))
```

output:

```
Enter a value for input A (0,1): >? 1
Enter a value for input B (0,1): >? 1
Output X is with V1: True
Output X is with V2: True
```

Comment: Thanks Dharman and Gabriele!